# Selecting the newest/latest addition to DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have a DB table with the list of actions performed over a specified `smlouva`. What I need is to select the newest/latest action performed for each `smlouva`, that is conditioned by timeframe and the action type.

The action table is as follows:

```
ID (int, Primary), action_ID(int), date(datetime), smlouvy_id(int)
```

And some of the data:

```
id      action  date                   smlouva_id
617872  -9      2016-08-25 08:43:00    114779
617871  -9      2016-08-25 08:43:00    114778
617867  -1      2016-08-25 08:30:00    114777
617865  -1      2016-08-25 08:27:00    114777
617864  -9      2016-08-25 08:27:00    114777
617839  -1      2016-08-25 08:24:00    114776
617838  -9      2016-08-25 08:23:00    114776
617837  105     2016-08-25 08:23:00    114775
```

And the constrains I want to apply are:

- Date: min and optionally max datetime from when to consider actions
- Actions: I need to only consider actions that are in this list (100, 101 ,104, 105, 106, 102, 103, -9)

Within those constrainst I want to select the newest/latest row for each `smlouva_id` - the row with the most recent `date`. In fact, I just need the `smlouva_id` and `action` of that row.

So for this data, the correct result would be:

```
id      action  date                   smlouva_id
617872  -9      2016-08-25 08:43:00    114779
617871  -9      2016-08-25 08:43:00    114778
617864  -9      2016-08-25 08:27:00    114777
617838  -9      2016-08-25 08:23:00    114776
617837  105     2016-08-25 08:23:00    114775
```

Or just as sufficient:

```
action  smlouva_id
-9      114779
-9      114778
-9      114777
-9      114776
105     114775
```

### TRIED and FAILING

I have tried several commands, however none of them seemed to be working.

```
SELECT action, smlouva_id 
FROM `pov_action` AS `O` 
WHERE ( 
  SELECT MAX(`date`) 
  FROM `pov_action` AS `I` 
  WHERE (
    (I.action = 100) 
    OR (I.action = 101) 
    OR (I.action = 104) 
    OR (I.action = 105) 
    OR (I.action = 106) 
    OR (I.action = 102) 
    OR (I.action = 103) 
    OR (I.action = -9)
  ) 
  AND (I.`smlouva_id` = O.`smlouva_id`) 
) 
AND (date >= '2016-08-25 08:28:07')
```

Or this one:

```
SELECT action, smlouva_id 
FROM `pov_action` 
WHERE (date >= '2016-08-25 09:23:09') 
  AND (
    (action = 100) 
    OR (action = 101) 
    OR (action = 104) 
    OR (action = 105) 
    OR (action = 106) 
    OR (action = 102) 
    OR (action = 103) 
    OR (action = -9)
  ) 
GROUP BY `smlouva_id`
(HAVING date = MAX(date)) -- optionally does not work with nor without
ORDER BY chdate DESC
```

Server version: 5.5.50-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Answer (score 1):

Use a derived table to find each smlouva_id's last date, using `GROUP BY`.

`JOIN` the table with that result:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
  join (select smlouva_id, max(date) as maxdate
        from tablename
        where action in (100, 101 ,104, 105, 106, 102, 103, -9)
        group by smlouva_id) t2
  ON t1.smlouva_id = t2.smlouva_id and t1.date = t2.maxdate
where t1.action in (100, 101 ,104, 105, 106, 102, 103, -9)
```